# How to take values from a list to a column of the data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a list in the form:

```
res[[1425006]]
#$AUCFSALL
#[1] 0.5144

#$COEFFS
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1

#$MODELS
#[1] "SX11" "SX12" "SX9"  "X2"   "X4"
```

Also, I have a table `TEST` that `dim(TEST)[1] = 1425006` (number of rows)
So now, I want to take all of the values `AUCFSALL` of the list `res` to put them in a column of `TEST`, for example: `TEST[, "AUCFSALL"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data showed, 'res' seems to be a nested list.  So, we extract all the 'AUCFSALL' elements by looping over through the `res` (assuming that there is only one value for 'AUCSFSALL' in each `list` element - as the OP showed only a single `list` element) to get a `vector` of equal `length` as the `nrow` of 'TEST'.  This can be assigned to create a new column 'AUCFSALL' in the 'TEST'.

```
TEST[, "AUCFSALL"] <-  sapply(res, `[[`, 'AUCFSALL')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
res <- lapply(1:3, function(i) list(AUCFSALL= rnorm(1),
         COEFFS= rep(1,5), MODELS= sample(LETTERS, 5)))
TEST <- data.frame(Col1= 1:3)
```

Comment: Sorry but It dont work. res[["AUCFSALL"]] show NULL.

Comment: @clairsang Looks like you have a nested list.  Can you provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: @clairsang Updated the solution.  Can you check if that works.